# Trying to Format Date and Time in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to format a Current_Timestamp to this format hh24:mi:ss dd-mm-yyyy in Oracle. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What has Stack become? I searched online, tried a few ways myself but I had a brain block and just needed an answer. Thanks to @OldProgrammer for the answer, and thanks astentx for downvoting and pandering. I did not realize I couldn't ask questions here that are answered in documentation.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2778710) It's not clear what did you search online and have tried, because you didn't post any code in your question, which is required. But you have posted **the exact format pattern**, then `to_char` should not have been so hard to discover. SO had always encouraged demonstration of your research result. Anyway, documentation is the first place to start with.

Comment: Sorry, next time I'll write out my life story for you.

Comment: If it means anything, I apologize @astentx . No excuses, just an apology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:mi:ss dd-mm-yyyy') from dual
```